# why my router doesn't work with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router, firebase-hosting

I just finish develop and deploy my first SPA Vuejs app on firebase https://newproject-dang.web.app/.
By running the app on localhost everything work fine, i can go to other component by directly typing on the URL but it's not working on firebase like typing this on the search bar doesn't work https://newproject-dang.web.app/calcul it work only by navigate from the navbar,

vue router index.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Meteo from '../views/Meteo.vue'
import Calcul from '../views/Calcul.vue'
import Todo from '../views/Todo.vue'
import Sort from '../views/Sort.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/meteo',
    name: 'Meteo',
    component: Meteo
  },
  {
    path: '/calcul',
    name: 'Calcul',
    component: Calcul
  },
  {
    path: '/todo',
    name: 'Todo',
    component: Todo
  },
  {
    path: '/sort',
    name: 'Sort',
    component: Sort
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    component: Home
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
})

export default router
```

navbar links

```
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li @click="toggle()"><router-link to="/meteo" >Méteo</router-link></li>
        <li @click="toggle()"><router-link to="/calcul" >Calculatrice</router-link></li>
        <li @click="toggle()"><router-link to="/todo" >To-Do</router-link></li>
        <li @click="toggle()"><router-link to="/sort" >Sort</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

firebase.json

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```